# Joining adjacent elements by rule

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have a list of strings:

```
lis = {"a","1","c","ef","g","2"}
```

and would like to join all adjacent non-numeric characters to produce:

```
res = {"a","1","cefg","2"}
```

Thanks for advice...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
StringJoin /@ SplitBy[lis, DigitQ]
```

yields:

> {"a", "1", "cefg", "2"}

Comment: Where did the "13" come from?

Comment: It was result from testing other inputs. Erroneously pasted result. I will edit. Sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`SequenceReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html):

```
ClearAll[sR]
sR = SequenceReplace[{p : __?(StringMatchQ[LetterCharacter ..])} :> StringJoin[p]]
```

or, a variation on  ubpdqn's approach, using `Split`:

```
ClearAll[splitAndJoin]
splitAndJoin = StringJoin /@ Split[#, Nor @@ (DigitQ /@ {##}) &] &
```

***Examples:***

```
lis1 = {"a", "1", "c", "ef", "g", "2"};
lis2 = {"a", "1", "c", "ef", "g", "2", "345", "A", "B"};

sR /@ {lis1, lis2}
```

> {{"a", "1", "cefg", "2"},
>   {"a", "1", "cefg", "2", "345", "AB"}}

```
splitAndJoin /@ {lis1, lis2}
```

> {{"a", "1", "cefg", "2"},
>   {"a", "1", "cefg", "2", "345", "AB"}}

Answer (score 2):

Using kglr's lists

```
a = {"a", "1", "c", "ef", "g", "2"};

b = {"a", "1", "c", "ef", "g", "2", "345", "A", "B"};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
StringJoin /@ SequenceSplit[a, d:{_?DigitQ} :> d]
```

{"a", "1", "cefg", "2"}

```
StringJoin /@ SequenceSplit[b, d:{_?DigitQ} :> d]
```

{"a", "1", "cefg", "2", "345", "AB"}

The accepted answer gives a wrong result for `b`

```
StringJoin /@ SplitBy[b, DigitQ]
```

{"a", "1", "cefg", "2345", "AB"}

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {"a", "1", "c", "ef", "g", "2"};
b = {"a", "1", "c", "ef", "g", "2", "345", "A", "B"};
```

Using `SplitBy` and `LetterQ`:

```
rule = s : {__String} :> If[MatchQ[s, {__?DigitQ}], Splice@s, StringJoin@s];

SplitBy[a, LetterQ] /. rule

(*{"a", "1", "cefg", "2"}*)

SplitBy[b, LetterQ] /. rule

(*{"a", "1", "cefg", "2", "345", "AB"}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `SplitBy`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
patt = StringFreeQ[DigitCharacter];
q[k_List, 
   p_] := (SplitBy[k, patt] /. {s__?(patt)} :> StringJoin[{s}]) // 
   Map[Apply[Sequence]];

a = {"a", "1", "c", "ef", "g", "2"};
b = {"a", "1", "c", "ef", "g", "2", "345", "A", "B"};

q[#, patt] & /@ {a, b}
```

A minor variant of @kglr's answer:

```
h = SequenceReplace[{p : __?(StringFreeQ[DigitCharacter ..])} :> 
   StringJoin[p]]


h /@ {a, b}
```

---

*Result:*

> {{"a", "1", "cefg", "2"}, {"a", "1", "cefg", "2", "345", "AB"}}